# "Restricted for" or "restricted to"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Is this sentence valid?

> Access to this content is restricted for our subscribers

or should it be:

> Access to this content is restricted to our subscribers

Comment: Both sentences are fine, but they mean different things.

Comment: yes what's the meaning of the first? I want to say that only subscribers can access the content

Comment: "restricted for" means something like "restricted for the benefit of, or on behalf of" our subscribers. But if you want to say "Only subscribers can access this content", why not just say that?  There is no reason you have to phrase it as a passive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first sentence ("restricted for") means that subscribers may not access the content. It implies, but does not absolutely say, that non-subscribers may access the content. This would be an unusual scenario.

The second sentence ("restricted to") means that subscribers, and *only* subscribers, may access the content.

Comment: The first sentence says that subscribers have some restriction regarding access, such as that there is some content that they can't access. It doesn't mean that all content is unavailable to them.

Comment: thanks for clarifying, I had it wrong for such a long time.. #embarassing

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are valid, though the second one is what you'd more likely encounter.

The first sentence implies that by being a subscriber, you are having your access restricted. The only scenario I can think of where this would be used would be in the case of a content filtering service, where a subscriber is explicitly prohibited from viewing certain content. Even then, it's a confusing way to word the concept.

The second sentence makes more sense, and implies that access to the content is only available to those who subscribe.